# Ways to handle MongoDB exceptions E11000

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, duplicates

i am new to webframework i am working on database , i am using createindex and aiming to prevent duplicate document ...

this is my code :
dbase.collection('registered_device').createIndex({"imsi" : 1, "imei" : 1},{unique: true}, function(err,res){}

and i was inserting sth like
dbase.collection('registered_device').insertOne(item, function(err,result){}
i have saw somee answer in stackoveflow ,
but it cannot solve my problem ,
i still run into
throw err;
^
my error was

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: null == { MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection:

can anyone help me?
thanks

Jeff

Comment: Could you please approve/upvote the answer if it was helpful. Otherwise let us know whats missing

Answer (score 0):

You have `unique` param set as `true`. It means

> Creates a unique index so that the collection will not accept insertion or update of documents where the index key value matches an existing value in the index.

In your case, you have duplicate `(imsi, imei)` values. Hence it throws `duplicate key error`.

So, if it is fine to have duplicate combination `(imsi, imei)` in your index, you can avoid that `unique` option.

Otherwise, you may need to alter your schema / make index unique.

I feel the below way efficient to delete the existing duplicates.

1. Create `mongodump` of existing collection
2. clear the collection - `truncate` all documents
3. Create the index - command which you have
4. Restore the dump using `mongorestore`

To handle the error once you removed the duplicates:

```
if (err) {
      if (err.code === 11000) {
        // Duplicate imei, imsi
        return res.status(HTTP_CODE).send({ success: false, message: 'imei already exist!' });
      }

      return res.status(Any_HTTP_ERROR_Code).send(err);
    }
```

Comment: yes because i dont want duplicate document in which i set duplicate imsi & imei as condition for now, its all i want, but
how can i handle the exception error, ?

Comment: Are you trying to delete duplicate docs by setting this index on your existing collection?

Comment: oh, sorry i should post more doc for this, yes my goal was to find Prevent duplicate exist in the collection, i was using  dbase.collection('registered_device').insertOne(item, function(err,result){}

Comment: Are you trying to find/prevent duplicates? Your statement is little misleading?

Comment: thanks @Gibbs, will let you know tmr  ,thanks in advanced